# Opt is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: clang, llvm

I just installed Clang/LLVM on Windows, using the pre-built binary LLVM-8.0.1-win64.exe.  Then I compiled a program to .bc using clang.

Now I want to run an opt pass, but I get

```
opt is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

The last entry in my PATH is C:\Program Files\LLVM, so that's not the problem.

Why do I get the error message that opt is not found when I was able to use clang?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` variable should contain `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin` directory.

Comment: I added that to my path, but it still does not work.  Same error message.

Comment: The strangest part is that Clang works perfectly but opt does not work.